# Выписать все строки на странице с нужной первой ячейкой

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Предположим есть страница

```
 Меню на шабаш 31 октября
 Антошка | Картошка | Лягушка
 Пюрешка | Поварёшка| Лягушка
 Котлетка| Картошка | Наташка
 Меню на повторный банкет
 Антошка | Плошка   | Лягушка
 Антошка | Картошка | Ляжка
 Сашка   | Картошка | Лягушка
```

Нужно выписать все вторые ячейки, где первая ячейка равна "Антошка". То есть:

```
 Картошка 
 Плошка
 Картошка
```

Но записать их подряд. Или хотя бы просто номера строк

```
1
5
6
```

Comment: Таблица же есть? Вот и покажите ссылку. Мало кому захочется для проверки решения пример рисовать. Без примера: доп. столбец с определением строк с нужными данными (`=ЕСЛИ(имена="Антошка"; МАКС(A$1:A1)+1`), результат получить функцией `ВПР`. Вариант без доп. столбца - формула массива.

Comment: Хм. Окей, вот из примера.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WocRLvqpSym88naTMLeA3IZIKpEfGVMOAdE0-7w-0r8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Вот да, нужно без доп столбца формулой массива. Но я никак не просеку как ими пользоваться. И даже пример уже пол часа гуглю (подходящий). Никак не нагуглится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавляем слева таблицы столбец, там пишем формулу, которая пронумерует нужные строки:

```
=IF(B2=$F$1,MAX($A$1:A1)+1)
```

Результат:

```
=IF(ROW(A1)>MAX($A$2:$A$8),"",VLOOKUP(ROW(A1),$A$2:$D$8,3,0))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Без допстолбца - формула массива:

```
=ArrayFormula(INDEX($C$2:$C$8,SMALL( IF($B$2:$B$8=$F$1,ROW($B$2:$B$8)-1),ROW(A1))))
```

Это для значения. Если достаточно номера строки:

```
=ArrayFormula(SMALL( IF($B$2:$B$8=$F$1,ROW($B$2:$B$8)),ROW(A1)))
```

Коротко - как работает формула. Функция `IF (ЕСЛИ)` формирует массив, состоящий из номеров строк и логических `FALSE`.  `SMALL (НАИМЕНЬШИЙ)` выберет нужный номер (`ROW (СТРОКА)` при смещении формулы вниз будет возвращать последовательно 1, 2, 3..., т.е. первое наименьшее значение, второе наименьшее...) . `INDEX (ИНДЕКС)` выберет из диапазона нужное значение.

Comment: Спасибо, это то что нужно. Постараюсь разобрать смысл отдельных элементов.